# How can I add an InkCanvas element to a Winform?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, inkcanvas

From what I understand so far, the [InkCanvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element is in the WPF Framework. To use that, I need an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control to host the InkCanvas element. I've been to the MSDN links, but the example it gives talks of creating a WPF User Control Library project and so on. It's not *that* bad, but it seems a bit much to just add a control to a Winform. Is there a simpler way to do this, or am I trying to oversimplify this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try something like this: `ElementHost host = new ElementHost(); InkCanvas ic = new InkCanvas(); host.Child = ic; Controls.Add(host);`?

Comment: Once I added the references to the needed assemblies, it was that easy. Thanks, @Vlad.

Comment: Glad that that helped. I'll copy the comment to an answer for other's reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
InkCanvas ic = new InkCanvas();
host.Child = ic;
Controls.Add(host);
```

As mentioned in comments, one needs to add the WPF assemblies as reference (WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework).